# AS3: Using Instance Variables as Default Parameter Values

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to use an instance variable as a parameter value in a method, but it is giving me an error.  "Parameter initializer is unknown or is not a compile-time constant"

I want to use a non-constant instance variable though, and I assume there has to be some way around this besides calling this method from another method.  Here is the code I'm referring to:

```
public function attack(target:Fighter=this.target):void {

}
```

Comment: You can't use this.target as an argument. Arguments are values come from outside the scope of your class. You have multiple options. For example, you can do this: `public function attack(target:Fighter):void {
   if(target == null) target = this.target;
}` or you can only attack if a target has been previously set(maybe using a `public function setTarget(newTarget:Target):void`, and so on. Hard to tell what would be the best solution without knowing more about your game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
public function attack(target:Fighter):void
{
    if(target == null)
        target = this.target;
}
```

and to be honest maybe it's easier to name one of variables `_target`  to avoid confusion. You can use `target = _target;` instead of `this.`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set an optional parameter that way. You can set optional parameters to a default value but not a reference. In this case if you want to keep it optional you could do something like this (or what @George Profenza suggested):

```
public function attack(target:Fighter=null):void {
    target = target ? target : this.target;
}
```

I see that you marked a correct answer already, but I'll explain that since you are defaulting  any null parameters to `this.target` you would benefit from using this solution so you don't have to pass `null` each time you call attack() i.e. - you can do `attack()` instead of `attack(null)`.